# Can't get the 3rd menu item to hide and show on hover

Tags: css

Here is my css for a 3 tier menu. I can hide the 3rd level but then I can't get it to show on hover of the 2nd level. This is for a wordpress side menu function.

```
ul.sidebar-navi-na {
    width:auto;
    background:#8f9044;
    border-right: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    padding:5px 15px 9px 0px;
    z-index:200;
    list-style:none;
    margin:5px 25px 0 0;
}
ul.sidebar-navi-na li.last {
    border-bottom:0px;
}
ul.sidebar-navi-na li a {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:95%;
    float:none;
    padding:2px 0px;
    margin:0px;
    color:#888;
    z-index:191 !important;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:none;
    font-weight:normal;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e9e9e9;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    font-size:15px;
}
ul.sidebar-navi-na li a:hover {
    color:#000;
    ?>;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul.sidebar-navi-na li {
    margin:5px;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
ul.sidebar-navi-na ul.sub-menu {
    margin-left:10px;
    display:none;
}
ul.sidebar-navi-na li.current_page_item ul, ul.sidebar-navi-na li.current_page_ancestor ul, ul.sidebar-navi-nali.current_page_parent ul {
    display:block;
}
ul.sidebar-navi-na li a {
    color:#000;
}
ul.sidebar-navi-na li ul.sub-menu a:active {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background:#fff;
    width:100%;
}
ul.sidebar-navi-na li ul.sub-menu {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background:#b0b152;
    width:100%;
}
ul.sidebar-navi-na li ul.sub-menu a:hover {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background:#fff;
    width:100%;
}
ul.sidebar-navi-na li ul.sub-menu .sub-menu a:active {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background:#fff;
    width:95%;
}
ul.sidebar-navi-na li ul.sub-menu .sub-menu {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background:#b0b152;
    width:95%;
}
ul.sidebar-navi-na li ul.sub-menu .sub-menu a:hover {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background:#fff;
    width:95%;
}
```

Comment: can you type your code up on codepen.io and provide us with the link. It will be easier for us to look into it.

Comment: What's up with the `?>;` in your CSS?

Comment: Well I pasted the css on codepen.. but not sure what else to do. This is for a Wordpress site submenu so I don't have a html file to add. the site is still in progress so not live to the public. I can send someone a log-in so they could see the site but really don't want to post that here?? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fqxgd/

Comment: I want to have a css menu that shows 
Link 
   Link A

Then when you click on Link A,  another level shows. 

Link 
   Link A
     Link 1
     Link 2
     Link 3

Comment: this is a sample of what I am trying to do http://kgeedesigns.com/safarioutfitters/asia-2/ but I want to hide the links Mongolia, Kyrgystan, Tajikistan unless you click on Argali.